# Login with stackexchange OpenID results is assoc_handle mismatch

Tags: support, openid

I'm trying to allow OpenID login using StackExchange OpenID to www.swi-prolog.org.  While the (Prolog implemented) OpenID client works find with myopenid, it fails for stackexchange.  What happens is this:

- I enter my OpenID (cannot include; too many links)
- This page is fetched, resulting in

  - OpenID Server='https://openid.stackexchange.com/openid/provider'
- It associates:

  - OpenID: Associating with '*as above (not allowed two links)*'
  - Reply: 
    dh_server_public:aMHmi2BmJOc7whlt1xQeh8xlSJMyWN8VWeXdbJaWsRKexs1TIF4Qxwrnlc6GRICn3j/S2bfeZO/h5CCUy6hmSHZuhCJgoSwK2vFIDXJIZvMQT8ETuh6vIW2mncqe7TaI1qHrQQSNe8ElcH+UsTO8uOhKSxk6hZ+dHco32qBI52k=
    enc_mac_key:IMVjsfslYMpxsLzNYtdpYb47gag=
    **assoc_handle:{635014607034840078}{uRdgBQ==}{20}**
    assoc_type:HMAC-SHA1
    session_type:DH-SHA1
    expires_in:1209599
- Then I login with stackexchange and grant the login to my (test) server
- Then, I get

  - Mode=id_res, validating response
  - OpenID: Lookup association with handle **'{635014604903141633}{2pwcuA==}{32}'**

As you can see, it is coming back with an new assoc_handle (shown in bold above)??

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Thanks --- Jan

Comment: I still do not know what is going on.  I tried the Python OpenID library.  This shows the same mismatch in association handle.  The library then continues with a openid.mode = check_authentication request.  I now implemented the same.  This works, but it still feels unsatisfactory.